# Multiple File Upload: isset($_POST['submit']) Returns False

Tags: php, html

I am using the following html form code to allow the user to select multiple files for upload.

```
<form action="uploadFiles.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

uploadFiles.php has the following code.

```
<?php
    echo "uploadFiles.php" . "<br>";
    print_r($_POST);
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
       echo "Post submit" . "<br>";
       if ($_FILES["file"]["error"][0] > 0)
       {
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"][0] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
              echo "No. files uploaded : ".count($_FILES['file']['name'])."<br>";
              echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][0] . "<br>";
              echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"][0] . "<br>";
              echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"][0] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
              echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][0];
        }
    }
?>
```

For some reason, isset($_POST['submit']) always returns false.  I get the following output

```
uploadFiles.php
Array( )
```

Comment: try print_r($_POST) to check post variables

Comment: Array() is all I get.  Thanks, OH

Comment: Are you calling `uploadFiles.php` directly (without going through the form), or is this what happens after you actually post the form data?

Comment: uploadFiles.php is called by clicking the submit button on the form.  It works for one file if I use <input type="file" name="file" /><br> instead but that only allows the user to select a single file.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't closing the `input` tags. Particularly, you aren't closing the `<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple>` tag, so possibly it isn't being added to the form's `$_POST` array correctly, and is instead being added to the `file` array.  Just a guess.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I made the change to the code in my question and also added the resulting output.  Unfortunately, while you were correct about my error, correcting it did not fix the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: You're not using IE9 or below, are you?

Comment: No.  I'm using IceWeasel which is a Debian version of FireFox.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be related to the size of the files.  If the files are 11 MB in size, the post only works with one of them.  If I select both $_POST is an empty array.  If the files are half that size, the post works with both with the following code.

HTML

```
 <form action="uploadFiles.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple"/></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit[]" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

uploadFiles.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
       if ($_FILES["file[]"]["error"] > 0)
       {
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file[]"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            $numFilesUploaded=count($_FILES['file']['name']);
            echo "No. files uploaded : ".$numFilesUploaded."<br><br>";
            for ($inc=0; $inc<$numFilesUploaded; ++$inc){
                echo "File " . $inc . ": " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$inc] . "<br>";
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$inc] . "<br>";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"][$inc] . "<br>";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$inc] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$inc];
                echo "<br><br>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```